# limit of the integral $\int_0^A \frac{1}{n!} [\log(\frac Bx)]^n~dx$ where $A,B$ are positive constants

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions, sequence-of-function

Let $A,B>0$ be fixed constants. I am trying to compute the limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n!} \int_0^A\left[\log\frac{B}{x} \right]^n~dx, $$
where $[-]$ is the floor function.

Can we interchange the limit and the integral? The integral is an improper integral because of $\log x$, so I'm not sure we can interchange. Also we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{[\log(\frac Bx)]^n}{n!}=0$ for all $x>0$ so interchanging the limit and integral seems to be awkward. Any hints for another approach?

Comment: If you did n integration by parts, you'd have one term with n!  The other terms would go to zero I'm the limit.

Comment: Perhaps taking $x=B \exp(-t)$ makes the problem easier to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first observe that for any $\delta > 0$, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n!}\int_{\delta}^A [\ln(B/x)]^n dx = 0. $$

So we assume that $A = B$, doing the substitution, $x = Be^{-t}$ then gives the integral to be $$ \dfrac{B}{n!}\int_0^\infty [t]^ne^{-t}dt $$

Proceeding from here by breaking into limits gives the answer